# How to get nearest greater time

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to get the nearest greater time in SQL Server, I have these values in my table called `TIMETEST` with columns `ID` and `Ti`:

```
ID     Ti  
---------------
1      01:00:00  
2      03:09:00  
3      07:00:00  
4      12:00:00
```

When I try

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM TIMETEST
WHERE ('1:59' < Ti)
```

It returns "03:09:00" which is correct but when I try

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM TIMETEST
WHERE ('12:00:00' < Ti)
```

I am supposed to get "01:00:00" but it returns an empty column.

Comment: Your time values are in a 24 hr format. So 1:00:00 is 1AM, which is not greater than 12:00:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

24 hour time versus 12 hour?

Try this instead to get 1 AM

```
SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM TIMETEST WHERE ('00:00:00' < Ti) ORDER BY Ti
```

If you want to do it via 12 hour time then some more logic will be needed but you would have to specific the period AM or PM.

Comment: Thanks alot am unable because of my reputation i think i would add some logic to your answer and use it

Comment: @Collins I am glad it helped you out.  I understand about the reputation I am trying to build mine too.  If it answered your question and you are able to accept the answer that would build us both up some.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work hope all works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.  First, you need `ORDER BY`.  In almost any case when you have `TOP`, you should be using `ORDER BY`.  So:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM TIMETEST
WHERE '1:59' < Ti
ORDER BY Ti ASC
```

Second, if the column is not a `time` data type, then the comparisons are done as strings.  To be safe, you can force conversion of the constant:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM TIMETEST
WHERE CAST('1:59' as TIME) < Ti
ORDER BY Ti ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have never heard of cast before but seeing your answer makes me feel i can use it without any other explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **@Matt** once again i was able to do it using 24 hour time
i added a column called DOW which means day of the week and i was using an Android code.
So if i try:
  `Select * from TIMETEST Where Ti > '12:00:00' AND DOW = 'Tuesday'  ORDER BY Ti`
and i get an empty set it means there is no column containing time between 12:01:00 and 23:59:00 my Android code would automatically change the query to
the next day which is working fine.
`Select * from TIMETEST Where Ti > '00:00:00' AND DOW = 'Wednesday' ORDER BY Ti`
Thanks for your answers.
Anyone who needs the Android code should comment and i would add it to the answer